# Is default home directory encryption with automount secure enough?

Tags: security, ecryptfs

Default Ubuntu desktop installation offers an option to encrypt my `/home`using `ecryptfs`, and it auto-mounts the home every time I log in.

If my PC had stolen, couldn't the attacker have just substituted my `/etc/shadow` file and login as me, gaining access to my files? If yes, what is a use case for this encryption then?

Comment: "If yes," No. But not encrypting `/` means they could add something to `/` to mail keyboard input (incl. your password) when you decrypt or decrypted your partition and access your data at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide your password during login to decrypt the home folder.

The password is *not* stored by Ubuntu in `/etc/shadow`. What you find there is only a hash of the password plus a short salt. When you log in, the password you entered gets hashed and then the hashes are compared.

It is not possible to retrieve the original password from that hash, except through trying all possible combinations until one matches.

So as long as you keep your password private and it is secure (long and complex) enough to withstand a brute-force (or dictionary) attack longer than the attention span of the attacker lasts, your encrypted home directory is safe.

---

To ecryptfs, it does not matter what hash is in the shadow file. It takes the password entered by the user at login and tries to decrypt the home folder with that. If it is the correct password, the decryption succeeds, if not, it will fail. By modifying the shadow file (or simply booting into a rescue mode root shell and resetting the account password), only the login password changes.

Encryption doesn't work by comparing hashes and deciding to let someone in or not, it works by doing lots and lots of maths using the password and the encrypted data on disk to get back the original data.

Comment: I meant, attacker can take random string, hash it, and put the result in shadow instead of my hash. So then, ecryptfs uses my user password as key to my files, right?

Comment: To ecryptfs, it does not matter what hash is in the shadow file. It takes the password entered by the user at login and tries to decrypt the home folder with that. If it is the correct password, the decryption succeeds, if not, it will fail. By modifying the shadow file (or simply booting into a rescue mode root shell and resetting the account password), only the login password changes. Encryption doesn't work by comparing hashes and deciding to let someone in or not, it works by doing lots and lots of maths using the password and the encrypted data on disk to get back the original data.